# Como pegar os dados de objeto array em javascript dentro de um FOR?

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar os dados vindos do objeto.

```
$scope.salvarHabilidades = function(pro){

    var valores = pro.filter(function(o,i){
        return o.habilidades == true;
    });

    console.log(valores);

    var dados = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= valores.length; i++){

        dados.push(valores[i].idhabilidade);

    }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não dá pra entender o que você quer fazer. Queres criar um array de objetos num for?

Comment: Exato! Tenho um FOR em javascript e quero montar um objeto array dentro dele

Comment: Tá, perai. Você acabou de editar a pergunta dizendo que quer "**pegar**" os valores dele. Por favor, se decida, já escrevi duas respostas diferentes desde que abri o post.

Comment: Quero montar um objeto array, dentro do FOR, pegando só os ids, entendeu?
Olha o meu código, dentro do FOR... No console aparece uma mensagem dizendo que idhabilidade está indefinido.

Comment: Se você tivesse explicado isso na pergunta seria bem mais facil

Comment: Imagina o tamanho que ficaria o título se eu colocasse tudo.

Comment: Pra isso que existe **o corpo** da pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só precisa criar fazer um `push` no *array*.

```js
var valores = [{descricao: 'Gesso convencional', habilidades: true, idHabilidade: 1}, {descricao: 'Gesso acartonado', habilidades: true, idHabilidade: 2}];

var dados = [];

for(let elemento of valores){
  dados.push(elemento.idHabilidade);
}

console.log(dados);
```

Ou usar a função [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (muito mais elegante, né).

```js
var valores = [{descricao: 'Gesso convencional', habilidades: true, idHabilidade: 1}, {descricao: 'Gesso acartonado', habilidades: true, idHabilidade: 2}];

var dados = valores.map(function(e) { return e.idHabilidade; } );

console.log(dados);
```

Comment: Estou fazendo isso, por que 1 ou mais dados, valores poderão vir... Como não sei quantos vem, faço um FOR e vou colocando os valores em um objeto array para mandar para a api!!
Você viu o print que coloquei aqui na descrição? Tem 2 valores dois objetos vindo.

Comment: Ok, é que na primeira versão da sua pergunta nada disto estava claro. Enfim, é isso que você precisa?

Comment: Estou tentando, já respondo.

Comment: Cara, o que apareceu no console foi:

[undefined, undefined]

Comment: É porque o `H` do seu código é minúsculo, no meu não.

Comment: Sim, deu certo... Seu código estava com H e é h kkkkkk.
Valeu

Comment: E seu eu quiser colocar mais um dado, além do id? kkkkk

Comment: `return {idHabilidade: e.idHabilidade, outraCoisa: e.outraCoisa }` Isso retorna um objeto com duas propriedades. (No caso de estar usando a função `map`).

Comment: Cara, não to conseguindo criar o objeto dessa forma que vc falou.
Fica assim:

["GESSO CONVENCIONAL", "1", "GESSO ACARTONADO (DRYWALL)", "2", opcao: "Cadastra habilidades", idusuario: 9]

E minha api não reconhece como objeto kkkk